# addEventListener, "change" and option selection

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to have dynamic select list populate itself, from a single selection to start:

```
<select id="activitySelector">
      <option value="addNew">Add New Item</option>
</select>
```

and then JavaScript code we have:

```
addEventListener("select", addActivityItem, false);
```

The problem is that various events don't fire when you have one item: not "change" because, the text is no different when you select that item; not "select" (as I have here), for a roughly similar reason, because I'm not really selecting anything because there's only one item. What is the event that should be fired here? It seems silly to list a blank item in my option list to fire the event, so I hope there is another solution. Or is that the best solution?

Comment: Seems like you want it to fire a separate onclick handler that checks the number of items, and if there is only one, calls addActivityItem.

Comment: I guess I'm just trying to figure out what event (if any) is getting fired when I click on the select item with only one item in it, because right now, the ones that should fire don't.

Comment: if you click, a click event will be fired. If you want to fire a select event you can fire explicitly
document.getElementById('activitySelector').click()

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You need a click listener which calls `addActivityItem` if less than 2 options exist:

```
var activities = document.getElementById("activitySelector");

activities.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var options = activities.querySelectorAll("option");
    var count = options.length;
    if(typeof(count) === "undefined" || count < 2)
    {
        addActivityItem();
    }
});

activities.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if(activities.value == "addNew")
    {
        addActivityItem();
    }
});

function addActivityItem() {
    // ... Code to add item here
}
```

*A live demo is [here on JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amullins/wL0e2fso/1/).*

Comment: I realized that the error was elsewhere in my code, and that the click event is the one I want after all. This is sort of what I did, and was along my thinking, so the confirmation is good. Thank you!

Comment: in your example link, wrote `changed` event, I thinks should be `change`

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that you used the **select** option, this is where you went wrong. **Select** signifies that a textbox or textArea has a focus.
What you need to do is use **change**.
"Fires when a new choice is made in a select element", also used like blur when moving away from a textbox or textArea.

```
function start(){
      document.getElementById("activitySelector").addEventListener("change", addActivityItem, false);
      }

function addActivityItem(){
      //option is selected
      alert("yeah");
}

window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me when I added () to the function call in the event listener, as in "...addEventListener("change", addActivityItem(), false);"

Answer (score 4):

Another way to make your code understandable is :

```js
let selector = document.getElementById("Selector"); 
let result = document.getElementById("result"); 

// when client clicked on select element 
selector.addEventListener("click", () => {
// if default value is changed
  selector.addEventListener("change", () => {
  // if value switched by client
    switch (selector.value) {
      case "add":
      //do somthing with  , "add" value
        result.innerHTML = selector.value;
        break;  // then take break
      case "remove":
      //do somthing with  , "remove" value
        result.innerHTML = selector.value;
        break; // then take break
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#Selector{
margin: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<label for"Selector">chose an option:</label>
<select id="Selector" name="Selector" >
      <option value="add">Add new item</option>
      <option value="remove">Remove existing item</option>
</select>

<div id="result">option selected : "The default value is first option"</div>
```