# Option click twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Whenever I try to click the dropdown list in , the first event is whatever is already loaded on the dropdown list, and the second event is whatever I click on the dropdown list. So essentially, there are two events happening, but I just want the second click.

HTML

```
<select class="pictureList" id="pictureList">
<option class ="option0" id="option0">select a picture</option>
<option class ="option1" id="option1">picture 1</option>
<option class ="option2" id="option2">picture 2</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById("pictureList").addEventListener("onkeyup", actionListener, false);
}, false);

function actionListener(event) {
    if(event.target == document.getElementById("pictureList")) {
    loadPicture();
    }
}

function loadPicture() {
    var picture = document.getElementById("pictureList");
    if (picture == "select a picture") 
    load;
    else if (picture == "picture 1")
    load;
    else if (picture == "picture 2")
    load;
 }
```

So everything gets loaded correctly, it's just that whenever I click the list to see the other options, it would load whatever is on the list already. For example, the list starts on picture 1 and I want to load picture 2. Then I click on the list to see the options, picture 1 gets loaded again, then I click on picture 2, and that gets loaded. I don't want picture 1 to get loaded again. I also tried onchange, but it still would do that.

Comment: You are looking for the `change` event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change It triggers when you actually select an option of a select.

Comment: Yeah I tried change and it would do that.

Comment: In your code, what `load;` does?

Comment: It just loads the picture. If I make a button that has an action listener, the picture would get loaded once. Idk if that helps. It's just like the first click to see the options keeps making it load.

Comment: You need to keep track (i.e. remember) if picture is already loaded or not. KeyUp event is going to fire no matter what.

Comment: I seeee. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try "change" instead of "onkeyup" in addEventListener.
Ex: document.getElementById("pictureList").addEventListener("change", actionListener, false);

Reference url: [addEventListener, "change" and option selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875414/addeventlistener-change-and-option-selection)

Or for more help you may send me a part of code on "mohit.tiwari@techinfini.com".