# Javascript alert message for winner while keeping score

Tags: javascript, alert

I'm a first semester student and am working on a simple application that will keep score for two people.  I have gotten to the point where names can be added, a number can be set for the "race" between the players and a button for adding one point at a time.  I want an alert to pop up for whichever player reaches the set 
"race to" number that states, x is the winner! or y is the winner! depending on who won.  I've tried to write an if statement, but lose functionality of parts of the javascript that is functioning(i.e. The set race number won't save when submit button is clicked)
[application page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuY1Y.png)

[Application page after inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLXcL.jpg)

here is the html i used...

```
    <article class="article1">
                <form id="player1"  method="post">
                    <h2>Player 1</h2> <input type="text" name="name" id="inputplayer" value="Player 1">
                    <h1 id="p1"></h1>
                    <button id="getname">Submit</button>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <button id="setscore1">Add Point</button>
                </form>
            </article><!-- end of player 1 form-->

            <article class="article2">
                <form id="middle" method="post">
                    <h1>Race to</h1><input id="inputrace" type="number" name="Race To" value="0">
                    <button id="setrace">Submit</button>
                    <h1 id="getrace"></h1>
                    <br>
                    <h1>Scores</h1>
                    <h3 id="score1">Player 1</h3>
                    <h3 id="getscore1"></h3>
                    <br>
                    <h3 id="score2">Player 2</h3>
                    <h3 id="getscore2"></h3>
                </form>
            </article><!--end of scores article-->

            <article class="article3">
                <form id="player2"  method="post">
                    <h2>Player 2</h2><input id="inputplayer2" type="text" name="name" value="Player 2">
                    <h1 id="p2"></h1>
                    <button id="getname2">Submit</button>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>          
 <button id="setscore2">Add Point</button>
    </form>
```

here is my javascript that allows me to change the player names and add the score....

```
<script>
   //Player 1 Name
        document.getElementById('getname').addEventListener('click',funcp1, false);
        function funcp1() {
            var playerName = document.getElementById('inputplayer').value;
            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = playerName;
            document.getElementById('score1').innerHTML = playerName;
            document.getElementById('inputplayer').remove();
            document.getElementById('getname').remove();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        //Player 2 Name
        document.getElementById('getname2').addEventListener('click',funcp2, false);
        function funcp2() {
            var playerName = document.getElementById('inputplayer2').value;
            document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = playerName;
            document.getElementById('score2').innerHTML = playerName;
            document.getElementById('inputplayer2').remove();
            document.getElementById('getname2').remove();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        //Player 1 score
        var number = document.getElementById('getscore1').innerHTML; document.getElementById('setscore1').addEventListener('click',function(){
            number++;
            document.getElementById("getscore1").innerHTML = number;
            event.preventDefault();        
        }, false);

        //Player 2 score
        var numberP2 = document.getElementById('getscore2').innerHTML; document.getElementById('setscore2').addEventListener('click',function(){
            numberP2++;
            document.getElementById("getscore2").innerHTML = numberP2;
            event.preventDefault();   
        }, false);
        //Race and score display 
        document.getElementById('setrace').addEventListener('click',funcr, false);
        function funcr() {
            var raceTo = document.getElementById('inputrace').value;
            document.getElementById("getrace").innerHTML = raceTo;
            document.getElementById('inputrace').remove();
            document.getElementById('setrace').remove();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
</script>
```

sorry in advance if i have used confusing tags or left out anything important that will help someone understand what I am trying to accomplish. Also, at this point, javascript is still very confusing for me as I have only weeks of experience.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to search for solutions already online, there are a number of things that come up with a a simple google search that are relevant to your question:

[Using alerts](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert)

[Using change event listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875414/addeventlistener-change-and-option-selection)

A change event is very similar to a click event, it just listens for a change in a given field.

What you are describing has a pretty straightforward implementation, you want to set a change event listener on the fields which hold the scores