# How to fire a function using <option>'s value in event listener

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm making a small project in Javascript which lets you click an area on a map of the US and it will tell you the timezone and local time of that area. I also have a dropdown `<select>` box that lets you pick the timezone manually.

I have different functions that update the local time depending on the timezone clicked/chosen. e.g.:

```
function localTimeAtz () {
    var offset = 9;
    var rawTime = utcTime - (3600000*offset);
    var time = new Date(rawTime);

    document.getElementById("timeZoneName").innerHTML = ("Alaska Standard Time");
    document.getElementById("localTime").innerHTML = (" " + time.getHours() + ":" + time.getMinutes());
  }

  function localTimeHtz () {
    var offset = 10;
    var rawTime = utcTime - (3600000*offset);
    var time = new Date(rawTime);

    document.getElementById("timeZoneName").innerHTML = ("Hawaii Standard Time");
    document.getElementById("localTime").innerHTML = (" " + time.getHours() + ":" + time.getMinutes());
  }
```

Here is the select box with each timezone:

```
  <select id="tzSelect">
    <option value="localTimePtz">Pacific Time Zone</option>
    <option value="localTimeMtz">Mountain Time Zone</option>
    <option value="localTimeCtz">Central Time Zone</option>
    <option value="localTimeEtz">Eastern Time Zone</option>
    <option value="localTimeAtz">Alaskan Time Zone</option>
    <option value="localTimeHtz">Hawaiian Time Zone</option>
  </select>
```

I want to fire the corresponding function each time a new timezone is clicked, so I have the value of each option the same as the name of the corresponding function.

Then I tried this:

```
  var selectBox = document.getElementById("tzSelect");

  selectBox.addEventListener("change", selectBox.selectedIndex.value);
```

Basically I'm trying to fire the function that has the same name as the value of the  chosen. But I can't get it to work.

Any idea how I can retrieve the value of an option and to fire the function with the same name as that value?

Comment: Second argument to `addEventListener` must be the handler function itself. You are passing a string.

Comment: Read about event listener here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this

```
selectBox.addEventListener("change", function(){

  //do something 

});
```

Reference

[addEventListener, "change" and option selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875414/addeventlistener-change-and-option-selection)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener